# Yocto recipe not extract archive

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to unpack .tar.gz file to my root during the building system, but it doesn't work because of an unclear reason for me. I did it in the same way as other recipes in my meta (which works fine), but in this case, **I have an empty directory in the target system root**. The recipe has the same name as tar.gz.

Based on [Yocto Project Documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bb-the-unpack) and my other experience it should work fine. I tried to remove manually **tmp**, **sstate-cache** directories and rebuild system, but it doesn't change anything. The recipe is building, but the **/my-app** is empty. Can I force extract my archive?

**Tree file:**

```
├── meta-my
│   └── recipe-my-app-files
│       └── my-app
|           └── my-app.bb
│           └── files
│               ├── my-app.tar.gz
....
```

**my-app.bb**

```
DESCRIPTION = "My Application package preinstall"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
RDEPENDS_my-app="bash qtdeclarative qtbase"
DEPENDS = "bash"

FILES_${PN} += "/my-app"

SRC_URI = "file://my-app.tar.gz"

BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "0"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
        # Create directories
        install -d ${D}/my-app
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in the [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bb-the-unpack) you provided that:

> The unpack call automatically decompresses and extracts files with
> ".Z", ".z", "**.gz**", ".xz", ".zip", ".jar", ".ipk", ".rpm". ".srpm",
> ".deb" and ".bz2" extensions as well as various combinations of
> tarball extensions.

it extracts `.gz` automatically into `${WORKDIR}`.

The issue with your recipe is that you are creating `/my-app` but not filling it with any content.

Keep in mind that the compressed file is unpacked under `${WORKDIR}`, so install it into `${D}/my-app`:

```
do_install(){
     # Create directories
     install -d ${D}/my-app

     # Install unpacked application
     # install -m 0755 app ${D}/my-app
     # ...
}
```

I do not know the content of your application, so change that according to it.

Comment: You're right, it was my misunderstanding. The extracted files to ${WORKDIR} need to be installed one by one in the target directory.